# Android SQLLite last 31 days data from current_timestamp column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to pull last 31 days data from SQLLite db, using below SQL. I already searched google and tried various options, while all SQL works i am not getting results as expected. For example in below screenshot you will see i do have record on 18-Sep but sql doesn't return any results...I am not sure what i am missing here..

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE TIMESTAMP > (SELECT DATETIME('now', '-30 day'))
```

[image]

Comment: have you store time stamp on data base ? If yes then simply crate current date and time stamp and minus 31 days from it and compare with stored time stamp as like SQL query

Comment: Try this query `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', '-31 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')`

Comment: Upendra i tried that no luck, as i said i tried all these options but something is fishy which is why i am not getting any record. Even though there is one already exist...

Answer (score 2):

Use between instead of Timestamp comparison directly -

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN datetime('now', '-31 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

This is because SQLlite stores dates in String format and doesn't have a standard DateTime format. So The direct comparison of String would fail. Hence using of the datetime function to compare dates with existing values helps.

Comment: I tried this too, but it doesn't pull any record. As you see in screenshot i do have 1 record matching but its not being pulled when i run this SQl.

Comment: @Akshay there is nothing fishy. Its just your timestamp format. SWL Lite doesn't support MMM type format. Change it to MM type so your month should be numeric. Check this for more formats - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Thanks Kapil, I found issue... The problem here is my column insert the current_timestamp whenever record is created but by dedefualt id didn't had any datatype. After creating datatype, i could see all SQL working...What i am wondering how did SQLLite created this table when i didn't had datatype for that column. I thought it should give me error...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as

`SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE TIMESTAMP  > datetime('now', '-30 days')`